# Delete record from HTML Table with delete Button secure?

Tags: php, html, get, search-engine, robots.txt

I developed a HTML table, which shows all records of my database. After each row I have a delete button, which sends a GET request to another php file, which deletes the entry

```
$urlToDelete = "DeleteRecord.php?id=" . $row['id'];
echo "<td>" . '<a href="' . $urlToDelete . '">Delete</a>' . "</td>";
```

The HTML table ist not secured. It's just a normal http link. I heard that it's possible that search engines could delta all the database.

I put this code into the file:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Is that enough to protect the database from search engines?

Thanks and best regards from Germany,
Chris

Comment: Why is your file not protected in the first place? You should be doing this using `.htaccess`. Leaving it unprotected will eventually find its way into some hacker's hand.

Comment: would a simple login system not be the most "secure" here?

Comment: Yeah you are right. Would be a possibility :) So 'noFollow' isn't enough?

Comment: I don't trust bots; period. Not with any code especially this kind, other than inside a protected folder and file. Don't play with fire, you will get burned.

Comment: Thanks for tip! I appreciate it very much. I'll do it with .htaccess :)